# possible ways to fake handprint recognition in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

For a game, I need to do a fake handprint gesture recognition, where the player has to press their palm on the multitouch screen to start playing. 
But I'm pretty much lost on how to implement this... I've tried to work with multiple buttons, but that didn't work as the buttons were invisible and many times not pressed by the player.  Can you suggest possible ways of building this?
I'm building this game in Unity3D and using touchscript plugin for windows 7 multitouch.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought: what happens if you test whether or not more than 5 touch events occurs at the same time?